# Returning to calling function when a http request has finished

Tags: android, androidhttpclient, android-async-http

I'm trying to do implement login using a ASP.Net Web Api into an Android application.
What I have so far are functions that work, just that I want to make the login request kind of synchronous instead of asynchronous.
I'm using **Android Asynchronous Http Client** like they say on their website.

```
public class ApiInterface {
    public static final String ApiURL = "http://******/api/";

    private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public static void get4Login(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
        return ApiURL + relativeUrl;
    }
}
```

And I have this function in LoginActivity:

```
private boolean doLogIn(String user, String pass) {
    boolean result = false;

    if (user.trim().isEmpty() || pass.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.add("user", user);
    params.add("pass", pass);

    ApiInterface.get4Login("Auth", params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable error) {
            Toast.makeText(MyApp.getContext(), "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            //***Here I want to set the doLogIn() function result depending on the response from the server;***
            Toast.makeText(MyApp.getContext(), "Lista sesizari incarcata!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should use an interface to return a callback to the parent

Answer (score 0):

On your `MyTextHttpResponseHandler` class should define a variable named result and set type is boolean,default to false,then define a method to get the result value,like

`public boolean getResult(){return this.result;}`

then you can change the `result` value on `onSuccess` and `onFailure` method.
Next your `doLogIn` method will like this

```
private boolean doLogIn(String user, String pass) {
//boolean result = false;

if (user.trim().isEmpty() || pass.trim().isEmpty()) {
    return false;
}
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.add("user", user);
params.add("pass", pass);
MyTextHttpResponseHandler myTextHttpResponseHandler = new MyTextHttpResponseHandler(this);
ApiInterface.get4Login("Auth", params, myTextHttpResponseHandler);
return myTextHttpResponseHandler.getResult();
}
```

Comment: the **return myTextHttpResponseHandler.getResult();** is executed before the onSuccess method.

Comment: oh,yes, but I don't suggest you use synchronous method to post a network request(you konw the reason),since you want to know the result of the request,maybe you want the result to invoke a method called `A(boolean)`,so to achieve the goal,you can let `doLogIn` to return void,and when your textHttpResponseHandler invoked `onSuccess ` or `onFailure` invoke `A(boolean)` with the result(if invoke `onSuccess ` then call `A(true)`,else if `onFailure` call `A(false)`)